# How do I get a list of tasks for an instance in cDevworkFlow?

Tags: c#

I have created a workflow definition which has many task steps and created instance for that.  How can i get list of all task and status of each task while running the instance?

Comment: You should provide what you tried so far and some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cDevWorkflow API is very powerful and it has the full support over your workflow tasks. With the help of deInstance class, you will get the list of all tasks created from an instance. The below code might help you:

```
        string connectString = ""; //get your workflow db connection string
        string currentUserId = ""; //get current userid
        string instanceId = ""; //get instance id to get the tasks

        deRuntime oRuntime = new deRuntime(connectString, currentUserId);
        deInstance oInstance = oRuntime.getInstance(instanceId);
        DataTable oTasks = oInstance.getTasks();

        //from the datatable oTasks you can see the status of each task
```

Hope this helps..!